# Google App Maker: Accessing widget's kind (component's class name) programmatically

Tags: google-app-maker

You are in a client script and taking the page.descendants (or pageFragment, popup, etc, whatever) and want to iterate its values, it's ok no problem:

```
app.popups.GlobalFilter.descendants.foreach(function (w){...})
```

But when you are in the closure you can't determine what kind of widget you dealing with, is it TextEdit or DatePicker, or Multiselect. All you have - properties (name, align, etc.). There is no property like `ComponentClass`, `WidgetClass` or `ClassName`.

You even can't set the values because you don't know what property you have to set (value for Datepicker and values for Multiselect) and it's type (Date for DatePicker and array for Multiselect).

I have to hardcode widget names with their types for now, but maybe I missed something and there is a way to determine widget/component class name?

Comment: Although I'm not entirely certain what you are trying to accomplish with this, you can get the className for each element by doing widget.getElement().className, however when you log each one in the console it will return something like this: app-TextBox HJNVY5C-b-a has-label app-NewPage1-Field5.

Comment: Thank you for advice. Honestly, I would like to stay in "Component" abstraction level and dont want to dive into html tags or DOM manipulation. 
I'm trying to make reusable function that will allow open my app with pre-filled  field values by URL-link.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to edit your question then. For example it would help to know what your URL link might look like and what type of information your link contains that might prefill your values in your app. Is the link always supposed to prefill the same form, or is the link more dynamic and can prefill any form? There might be another way to go about what you are trying to accomplish, your question however is too broad to determine that.